# Access an element of subscribed array within component

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, binding

I have an angular project with several arrays in my component which I am accessing directly from the html template via binding. As an example, in my component I have:

```
public materials = []
```

This is populated by a service and is accessed in my template as

```
    <section>        
      <h3>Total Materials</h3> {{ materials[0].materials_aud | number:'1.2-2' }} 
    </section>
```

This works fine, however I am performing calculations on this data from within the html and it is becoming very verbose (read: ugly) and difficult to maintain. I would like to be able to access these array elements from within my component as variables and do the calculations within the component (or at least in the template using these variables), however I am unsure how to do this. New to angular and understand the principles of subscribing to observables and casting them to an array but not accessing the array after it is populated. It seems logical that once the array has data, I should be able to access it. I have attempted to access the array via ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit {
    this.materials_total = this.materials[0].materials_aud
}
```

but I get an error:

> angular Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'materials_total' of undefined

Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: can you share content of the materials? or share data you want to achieve so we can help you further.

Comment: An example result of the materials array after it is populated is just Data is: 
      Array(1)
      0: {materials_aud: 1639737.8315859856}
     length: 1
     __proto__: Array(0)

Comment: So i just want to be able to assign the result  that index to a single variable

Comment: try setting your variable materials_total: any;

Comment: Do you have an observable from your service? Try `observable.subscribe(data=>this.materials=this.process(data))`.

Comment: The data from the observable needs to be passed into an array (via an interface). If I use 'any' as the type, I wind up with a second array assigned to 'this.materials', but what I need is just one element of that array assigned to the variable. Not sure if this makes sense?

Comment: You did not include code where materials is populated, so it's not clear how you are populating the array. I do not understand what you mean by passing data from observable into an array.

Comment: If you only need one element, you can do this `observable.subscribe(data=>this.materials_total=data[0].materials_aud)`. The reason you can't access it in ngOnInit is that subscribe callback has not been called. In general, you want to manipulate data in subscribe callback. If you have to access it outside the callback, you need to check that it is populated (null check, array length check, a flag etc.).

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realise that you could access the index of data directly. That fixes it :) Thanks indeed.